# NodeJS/ ReactJS: Displaying different UI for different users

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This questions stems from a confusions between how nodejs routes and requests interact and pass context into reactjs.

**My use case:**

User A is an Admin.
User B is *not* an Admin

When user A gets routed to a page with a react component, I want user A to have a different UI (perhaps access to an Admin Panel).

When user B gets routed to a page with the same react component, I want user B to not have access to any UI that is for Admins.

What is the best way for reactjs and nodejs routes to communicate that User A gets special ui, and User B does not.

**What I looked into that doesn't seem to work:**

LocalStorage - there is a disconnect between nodejs server side local storage and client side storage.

SessionStorage - same as above

How is this done correctly with nodejs and reactjs. An example would be awesome!

Comment: What are you using for routing?

Comment: @erichardson30 nodejs/express with passport for routing. See a related question I posted out of confusion for sample code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104765/react-cookie-never-being-set-in-nodejs

Comment: use react-router. config express with `app.get('*'....` to routing with react-router, in this module you set that show components depending on the routes, so easier

Comment: Is there another way without react-router? this application is already fairly large and isn't fully built in react.

Comment: Then I would think that logic would need to be built in to the express routing